# jQuery How to access var inside function

Tags: jquery, asp.net

How I can access variable which is inside jQuery function, below is the code. I need inside var lat, lng to store in hiddenfield or label in the later stage. I have tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
    else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}

    var x = null;

    function showPosition(position) {
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var lng = position.coords.longitude;

        x+= lat; 
        alert(lat+ " " +lng);
    } 
 /*
  * I have tried this way for testing  */
   alert(x);
</script>
```

The value for x is undefined.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: the more i read your code the less i understand it. What is x?

Comment: @roasted x is just a global variable

Comment: try `showPosition(2000)` (change the value of position) and then call `alert(x);` will work ( i mean the value will be populated in `x`)

Comment: @SLaks what is other way to access user lat and lng as I need these two values and store in my DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run your code `alert(x)` is being triggered straight away. This means that in browsers that support GeoLocation `x` hasn't had a chance to be set yet which is why you're getting the `undefined` message.

The way to do this is:

```
var x = 0;

if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, error);
} else {
    test(); // call other function or display error message 
}

function showPosition(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    x += lat;
    test();
}

function error(){
    console.warn('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
}

function test() {
    alert(x);
}
```

It looks like you've copy and pasted the code from W3Schools so you'll get an `undefined` error if `navigator.geolocation` isn't `true` as `x` isn't a DOM element so it doesn't have an `innerHTML` property.

In the above code `test();` is used to show a pop up box with the value of `x`. In your code `test();` should be the next function you want to run. For example, it could be a function that fetches data based upon the user's current location (if available).

**UPDATE:** Here's an example of populating hidden fields with the data.

```
var lat = 0, lng = 0;
function showPosition(position) {
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lng = position.coords.longitude;
    test();
}
```

Then use:

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="latInput" />
<input type="hidden" id="lngInput" />
```

JS:

```
function test(){
    $("#latInput").val(lat);
    $("#lngInput").val(lng);
}

// or

function test(){
    $.post("your-script.php", { lat: lat, lng: png })
    .done(function(data) {
       // success
    })
    .fail(function() {
        // fail
    });
}
```

Comment: its working! How can I access function test into hidden field or a label to store in DB.

Comment: isnt it same as my previous code, I want to access the var lat and lng to store in my DB on server side. I have tried this var some = test(); nothing shows

Comment: @VenkaYeluri - I've just updated it with a few examples, they should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the variable `lat, lng` out side function then you would be able to access them in the code after the declaration. You have to call the function `showPosition` first before you access them.

```
var lat, lng;
function showPosition(position) {
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lng = position.coords.longitude;

    x+= lat; 
    alert(lat+ " " +lng);
}
```

Comment: You have to call the function first before you access them.

Comment: @VenkaYeluri - if the browser you're using doesn't support Geolocation then your function won't be called and the variables will be undefined.

Comment: @joe you may be right as I have tried different way. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/sqZmU/

```
(function () {


    var x = "";

    function showPosition(position) {
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var lng = position.coords.longitude;

        x += lat;
    }

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
    /*
     * I have tried this way for testing  */
    $('button').on('click',function(){
        alert(x);
    });

})();
```

Comment: a blank pop-up msg box appears

Comment: I can see msgBox, as you have defined x="" so it appears a blank msgBox

Comment: ya, seems like SLaks commented it, this works asynchronously. So the only way is to use it inside showPosition() function or call it later. I'll update answer soon

Comment: I have tried your updated code, its working jsfiddle but not my compiler. If you remove the button click function in jsfiddle then a blank msgBox appears

Comment: asynchronous, this is the term you should look at to understand why this behaviour append

Comment: BTW, i don't know what the term compiler means when it comes to javascript

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to return the value of `x` by using it as local variabel using `var x` inside the function show position.

Comment: I have tried this, function showPosition(position) {
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            return lat;
        }
        var x = "showPosition(position)";
        alert(x);

Answer (score 0):

You have to call function `showPosition()` before you `alert(x)` because x is only populated when the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you have to call the function `showPosition` to see its effect.

Second thing, do not try to access variable `x` like that. Instead of that you can return the value you required from that function.

Comment: the problem with your work is the function `showPosition` has not been called. You have used `alert` function. Are you sure that `alert` function within `showPosition` has been called. 


Instead of `alert` function, I prefer `console.log` function and you can see the log using **console** of browser.